# Badge Progress show 83 edit, but not received Strunk and White Badge

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges

The question is my Badge Progress show 83 edit I made, but still not received Strunk and White Badge. Why?

Comment: How long have you waited? At least wait a day or two for the badge script to run.

Comment: About 1 hour and above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most badges aren't awarded instantly. Give it a day or so and if you still don't have it, let us know and we'll take a closer look.